# css text-align gap between text

Tags: html, css

I have a column of text where I would like to minimize the gap between the words. I have found `text-justify` but it is only supported by IE.

Is there some other css property that would make this look better?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a narrow column like the one in the screenshot, `text-justify: newspaper` would create gross spacing between letters. There just isn’t a way to make such a text well-justified, even on IE, without hyphenation.

Hyphenation can be achieved in almost all browsing situations by using avaScript-based hyphenation, such as [Hyphenators.js](http://code.google.com/p/hyphenator/), and backing it up (for non-JS browsing) with the `hyphens` property (with prefixed versions too) in CSS. You can additionally use `text-justify: newspaper` for IE, but consider whether it is really an improvement.

See [demo](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/test/just.html).

If you use `text-justify`, add `text-justify: distribute` before `text-justify: newspaper`, because the former is included in the working draft [CSS Text Module Level 3](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-text/).

Comment: Thanks Jukka... Very, VERY nice solution! Thank you for pointing me to this!

Comment: Jukka, I downloaded this library but I am getting: `An Error occurred:
Access to restricted URI denied`. Would you know what's wrong? I didn't change anything and simply opened the sample file in the downloaded folder. I've looked on the net but can't find anything useful. Thanks

Comment: @user1709311, it seems that due to the techniques used (Ajax), Hyphenator.js does not work if you try to use it locally (in your computer) so that you refer to a local copy of it. But it works if you refer to the remotely hosted service, as in my example, or uploaded onto your server (the same where your pages are).

Comment: Jukka, thank you again. I just figured it out by reading his docs (which weren't easy to locate BTW). I now have it working. Thanks again, and if we were closer, I'd buy you a beer! :)

Answer (score 2):

you can either, `left`, `center`, `right`, or `justify` the text. Currently, your text is justified. You can set the text alignment doing something like:

```
text-align: left;
```

That will left align the text.

Comment: The sample in the question clearly implies that `text-align: justify` has been used; the question is how to make the justification better.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the [word-spacing](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/text.html#propdef-word-spacing) property with a negative value, but as the specified it is browser-dependent. That is if you want to keep your justified text, but that causes larger and uneven gaps by definition. Why don't you use `text-align: left`?

Answer (score 0):

`text-align: justify` will justify align text by increasing space between words.

If you add `hyphens: auto;`(need prefix for each browser) to your CSS. It will add hyphens at the last word of some lines, while preserving the justify align.

But it will only work on IE 10+, Firefox 6+ and Safari 5.1+, not on Chrome nor Opera. So the better way to solve your problem, is increasing the column width, and decreasing the font size.

Read this for more info: http://skinnywhitegirl.com/blog/web-typography-hyphenation-justification/475/

Comment: The `text-justify` property does not cause justification; it just affects (on IE) the way justification is performed, due to `text-align: justify`.

Comment: the CSS 2.1 spec explicitly says about `text-align: justify`: “Note. The actual justification algorithm used depends on the user-agent and the language/script of the text.”

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela didn't refer to the spec, I read it on w3schools as "Stretches the lines so that each line has equal width." Obviously not precise enough. thanks.